# Is it possible to write a generic rust function telling you if a given enum variant is in a container?

Tags: generics, enums, rust

In other words, if you have:

```
enum Foo {
   Bar(String),
   Buzz(i32)
}
```

Can you write a generic function that checks if a vector contains a particular variant (where the desired variant is the generic argument)?:

```
fn f<T>(x: Vec<Foo>) -> bool {
    for i in &x {
        if let T(...) = i {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Then call with something like:

```
assert!(f::<Foo::Buzz>(x));
```

I think this might be equivalent to asking if `matches!` could be a generic function instead of a macro.

Comment: you seem to be asking for something very specific. do you need it to be so specific, or is it ok to solve your problem another way? for example, do you _need_ the variant to be used as the generic parameter, or is that just one particular way you thought of approaching your wider task?

Comment: I'd like to notice a couple semantic mistake also: 1) f should return bool; 2) `f` usage with `assert!` requires a parameter.

Comment: As noted elsewhere, you can't use the enum variant as a generic argument, but you can use https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.discriminant.html to implement something similar to this, using a function parameter rather than a generic type.

Comment: @Kitsu oops, fixed

Comment: @joelb I'm asking it specifically because I am trying to understand if this is a language limitation with variants/generics. Luki446's answer suggests it is. It might still additionally be useful for people though to know what the alternatives are when you run into a situation where your first thought is to want this feature.

Comment: @DanielWagner-Hall that is an interesting building block to know about, but if I'm understanding correctly it requires you to first build an instance of the variant, which requires knowing what data to put in it, which seems to defeat the point of the very use case the documentation is promoting? Unless there is an easy way to fudge that as well?

Comment: @DanielWagner-Hall Heh, I started to wonder why there couldn't just be a version of discriminant that lets you specify which variant as a generic argument, but that again would require this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't use enum variant as a generic argument because it is not a type.